# Issues with NameSpace import in Xquery

Tags: xml, namespaces, xquery, oxygenxml

Im trying have my namespace imported but for some reason it will not budge.
Ive tried this as well as adding the path

```
import schema namespace r = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" at "Assignment-Xquery3.xsd";
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Error in schema http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema: No valid schema was found
```

I tired "-Instance" as well but to no luck. I am run Saxon EE. I have tried to add my file path. Im not sure whats wrong, This is the template that my teacher has provided us.

The rest of  my code if needed:

```
import schema namespace r = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" at "Assignment-Xquery3.xsd";
<provider>{
    for $r in
    distinc-values(doc("instance.xml")/r:patient/r:treatment/r:provider)
    return
        <info>
        <patient>{string($r)}</patient>
            {for $rr in doc("instance.xml"/r:patient
            where $r = $rr/r:treatment}
            return
                <treatment>
                    <id>{$rr/r:id/text()}</id>
                   <diagnosis>{$rr/r:diagnosis/text()}</diagnosis>
                   <drug>{$rr/r:drug/text()}</drug>
                </treatment>

        </info>
}</provider>
```

[image: This is the template my teacher provided us]

Comment: If you want to use namespaces in your XQuery path expressions then you use `declare namespace r = "http://example.com";`. A schema is used for schema-aware XQuery (which Saxon EE supports) but I don't see any attempt to use schema types in your XQuery code. And it is not likely that the target namespace of your schema `Assignment-Xquery3.xsd` is the W3C XSD namespace, as that is the namespace of the schema language itself.

Comment: so you're suggesting just to remove the `schema` part aka `import namespace r = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";`? If so Im getting another error that says: `Unexpected token name "namespace" beyond end of query`

Comment: I suggested to declare the namespace as shown. If you want help to import a schema in a meaningful way then show us the relevant part of the schema (targetNamespace).

Comment: this is the schema tag in the `Assignment-Xquery3.xsd` file we were given: `<schema targetNamespace="http://cs548.stevens.edu/clinic/db" elementFormDefault="unqualified"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://cs548.stevens.edu/clinic/db"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">` I can add the whole file if you'd need it

Comment: If you want to import that schema then you need `import schema namespace r = "http://cs548.stevens.edu/clinic/db" at "Assignment-Xquery3.xsd";`. To simply use the namespace in your XQuery code it would also suffice to use `declare namespace r = "http://cs548.stevens.edu/clinic/db";`. The XQuery code itself should rather use `group by` I think but that is a different issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve, but it's very clear what you are doing wrong.

When you write

```
import schema namespace r = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" at "Assignment-Xquery3.xsd";
```

you are

(a) trying to load a schema at the location "Assignment-Xquery3.xsd". That's probably OK; I dare say there is probably a valid schema at that location.

(b) asserting that the schema at that location has a target namespace of "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema". This seems highly unlikely, since user-written applications are very unlikely to want to access the schema for schema documents.

(c) binding the prefix "r" to that namespace. Again this seems implausible, (i) because the usual prefix that people use for that namespace is "xs" or "xsd", and (ii) because you go on to use the name `r:treatment`, and there's certainly no name in this namespace with local name "treatment".

I strongly suspect, though I can't be sure, that you don't really want to import a schema at all; you just want to bind the prefix "r" to some namespace (perhaps `http://www.example.org/review`, but we can't be sure). If that's the case, then you simply want

```
declare namespace r = "http://www.example.org/review";
```